# 'Too Many Values to Unpack' when working with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I am currently working with numpy arrays and training. My code is built around the following links, with a few changes to integrate a database from Kaggle.

https://github.com/thisisiron/TF2-GAN/blob/master/cgan/train.py

It looks to me like images, labels are some form of dummy variables for some reason.

In the loop:

```
for images, labels in train_dataset:
            gen_loss, disc_loss = train_step(images, labels)
```

Where train_dataset is set to be the numpy of training samples(no labels).So it is a set of filenames

I have a few ideas of what to do, not too sure

Comment: Made some changes using np.append(train_dataset, y_train).

Comment: The current error: numpy.ndarray not callable

Comment: That loop assumes `train_dataset` contains image and label pairs.  Don't use that loop form it only has images.

Comment: Thank you. I recently made changes. So I used a while and did images=train_dataset[i] and labels=y_train[i]

Comment: The error is now something to do with layers and dimensionality. I eel lost and Don't really know what to do. It says expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1 for dense_57